# Why fopen_s returns EEXIST (errno 17) when opening file for reading

Tags: c, fopen, c11, tr24731

When I execute `fopen_s(&fid, FILE_NAME, "r")`, `fid` is null and `errno` is 17.
How is this even possible that when I try to open a file for reading I get `EEXIST` error?

Comment: Sometimes, it has to do with an invalid path.  Specifically, if a directory is specified in FILE_NAME, and that directory does not exist...   It would be helpful if more detail were supplied so that the context of the call could be examined.

Comment: When I change the directory name of the file name I get the error: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Do you know the file you are trying to open exists? Do you know if the program you are running has permission to read the directory and file?

Comment: Yes, it exists. And yes I have permissions.
No permission is a different error. 

EEXIST is "File exist" error which should only happen if the open operation doesn't make sense if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried using ifstream and it works. wt*??

Answer (score 3):

`errno` is not meaningful after a call to `fopen_s`. The error code is in the return value of the function.

Source: C11 Annex K, [K.3.5.2.2 The freopen_s function, paragraph 9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.2.1p9):

> The fopen_s function returns zero if it opened the file. If it did not open the file or if there was a runtime-constraint violation, fopen_s returns a nonzero value.